# How to handle exceptions that occur in let bindings or body

Tags: exception, clojure, autocloseable

How does one deal with exceptions that could occur in the bindings or body of a `let` statement using the same finally block? Ex:

```
(let [connections (create-connections)] 
  (dostuff)
  (close connections))
```

If `(create-connections)` or `(dostuff)` fails, I want to `(close connections)`. Some options:

Option 1:

```
(try     
  (let [connections (create-connections)] 
    (dostuff))
  (finally (close connections))
```

This obviously doesn't work though since `connections` is not in scope in the finally block.

Option 2:

```
(let [connections (create-connections)]
  (try
    (dostuff)
    (finally (close connections)))
```

This option only catches exceptions that occur in the `(destuff)` call though and not those that occur in `(create-connections)`.

Option 3:

```
(let [connections (try 
                    (create-connections)
                    (finally (close connections)))]
  (try
    (dostuff)
    (finally (close connections)))
```

This also doesn't work since `connections` is not in scope for the finally statement inside the let binding.

So what's the best way of dealing with this?

Comment: How could you possible close connections that you failed to create? It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Here's an interesting discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/hsh-H8SxNHw - especially this comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/hsh-H8SxNHw/Hm0Nh2MsZGIJ

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The built in `with-open` works on anything you can  call `.close` on, so the normal approach is to use something like:

```
(with-open [connections (create-connections)] 
    (do-stuff connections))
```

and handle errors opening connections within the code that failed to open them. If create-connections fails to open one of the connections then perhaps a `try` ... `finally` block within create-connections is a cleaner place to handle that sort of error condition.

Comment: I think you're right about handling connection open failures within create-connections. Failures while creating a connection is really a separate concern from failures that occur while doing stuff, therefore the handling can be separate. Good call.

Comment: Its unfortunate you accepted this answer, as it does not address the more general question you bring up, but only the specific example you gave.